# Python - Issue with plotly graph on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I am plotting a graph with plotly on jupyter notebook.
The actual graph should look like this.[image]

However, I am getting this.
Please how can i correct this.
[image]

Please see below code:

```
# Setting layout for our plot
layout = go.Layout(
    title='Stock Prices of Tesla',
    xaxis=dict(
        title='Date',
        titlefont=dict(
            family='Courier New, monospace',
            size=18,
            color='#7f7f7f'
        )
    ),
    yaxis=dict(
        title='Price',
        titlefont=dict(
            family='Courier New, monospace',
            size=18,
            color='#7f7f7f'
        )
    )
)

tesla_data = [{'x': tesla['Date'], 'y': tesla['Close']}]
plot = go.Figure(data=tesla_data, layout=layout)
#plot(plot) #plotting offline
iplot(plot)
```

Please see snapshot of my data
[image]

Comment: You probably just need to sort your date column! Can you share the url of your data?

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: Please provide a [mcve](/help/mcve). In particular share your data.

Comment: Please I have included snapshot of my data